# How to write trigger in sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have condition to insert record in table for that i want to write trigger.

For an instance : when A code is getting inserted in the table at the same time insert B code as well in that table.

Need trigger query

Comment: There is not enough informations about your problem. Try to ask a question according to  the rules: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want to Write the trigger which insert record on the table , when the A code is getting inserted in the table at the same time i want a trigger to insert B records as well. Hope i am more clear about the issue i am facing.. appreciate your help ony advance

Comment: How many rows are you inserting at the same time? Only one, or more than one?

Comment: More than one since its based on region so it will insert code with country code for eg: Aind where A is code and ind is country code